# Jade -p/--path option, what does it do?

Tags: pug

I've started to use Jade and it's wonderful.

I'm looking at the "-p/--path" option, which according to the help menu is:

```
-p, --path <path>      filename used to resolve includes
```

I would expect this is some sort of "base" directory for the include/extend directives.

Consider the following template template.jade:

```
include bar.jade
```

And the following execution:
   jade -p foo template.jade

Jade will try to load foo/bar.jade .

This does not seem to work.
 Am I interpreting wrong the meaning of this option?
If so - what this it supposed to do?
Assuming I'm wrong - is there anyway to achieve what I'm looking for? (relative includes)

Many thanks.